# How to override password and confirmation for Users model in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an app where there are users and owners. Owners have many users and every user can `belong_to` one owner. It's the same model and the associations are built inside the models. The problem is that I want to be able to add and change the field values of them (e.g. `user.department`) and `has_secure_password` (`password`, `password_confirmation`) prevents me from doing so, as I have to enter a password & confirmation for the values to be persisted.

Can anyone tell me If I can bypass the password+confirmation validation for the owner ?

I am using the rails tutorial by Michael Hartl https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
has_secure_password validations: false
validates :password, :password_confirmation, :presence => true, :if => :password
```

Is one way to achieve that.

Comment: Thank you very much. At first it didn't work but I found out that I need to remove my has_secure_password (I had them both included). I would be glad If you'd explain why did you put this ":if..." in the end.

Comment: It asks for validations for password & password confirmation if params[:password] are present. So for all instances where you require password, it requires it to be found.